# Azure service bus - "Count of Active messages" issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-servicebus-topics, keda

Azure service bus specific topic's "Count of Active message" metrics grows suddenly, though there is no visible spike in the incoming messages count. These behaviour is been observed in last couple of weeks not before.

Whenever "Count of Active message" increases the message processor application (AKS pods)  count increases based on auto scale settings but still the "Count of Active message" not decreasing.

In order to bring down the "Count of Active message", the message unit of Azure service bus service needs to be increased from 2 to 4, once after that "Count of Active messages" reduces & "it not grows thereafter. Once we decreases the message unit from 4 back to 2 after sometime "Count of Active messages" increases again. Remember there is no visible spike in the incoming message count.

This behaviour is confusing, how increasing message unit of service bus reduces "Count of Active messages"? but the increasing message processor application's (AKS pods) count not reducing the "Count of Active messages" as expected.

Note: Increasing Azure Service bus's message unit comes with additional cost around $1200k, not a long term solution.

SDK Used: "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2"

Message processor is "ServiceBusTrigger" based Azure function application hosted on AKS with KEDA based HPA enabled.

```
    [FunctionName("servivebusprocessor")]
    public async Task ProcessAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("nameofservicebus", "topicname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnString")] string serviceBusMessage,
        [ServiceBus("topicname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnString", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)] IAsyncCollector<Message> messageCollector)
      {
          //logic
      }
```

Comment: Have you raised a support case with Azure?

Comment: Not yet, thought of check it here first.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you're running into something that is internal to the service.

Comment: In that case, what you suggest?

Comment: Support case with Azure to get to the messaging team.

Comment: Seems to be strange, it's worth checking out. The values of Message Counts which is sum of (Active + Scheduled + Dead-letter + Transfer + Transfer dead-letter). Expected is Message Count also should increase proportionally with Active count. If discrepancies yeah raising support ticket always best option